# Upgrade NGNIX version on MacOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, webserver, version, certbot

I have the current version of ngnix of:

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.6
```

- now I want to upgrade it, but do not know how?
- I have found these resources: https://medium.com/@soban1193/upgrading-nginx-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-c0ad9116cf87 and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-update-nginx-and-should-i-update-it but they seem for upgrade using ubuntu commands.
- I want to know how I can make the upgrade using macos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upgrade nginx on macOS, use Homebrew:

1. Update Homebrew

   ```
   brew update
   ```
2. Upgrade nginx

   ```
   brew upgrade nginx
   ```
3. Cleanup old artifacts

   ```
   brew cleanup
   ```

[Reference](https://www.javacodemonk.com/installing-nginx-on-macos-mojave-using-brew-4bb0ec31)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Homebrew to manage package on MacOS.

For nginx, you can use `brew install nginx`

Comment: I already do have ngnix installed.. I want to upgrade it.. how do I do that specifically?